# GetCipher("AES/GCM/NOPADDING") got invalid parameters passed to GCM error

Tags: powershell, bouncycastle, aes-gcm

I am trying to make my PowerShell script encrypt/decrypt message using AES/GCM/NOPADDING. My key is a pair of public/private key string with format PKCS#8. My private key length is 1624 bytes.

Here is part of my script, it break at $cipher.Init with exception "**invalid parameters passed to GCM**":

```
Add-Type -path "BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll"

$privateKey="<long long string with 1624 bytes>"
$message = "Plaintext message"
$messageBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($message)
$key = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($privateKeyB)
$IV = New-Object byte[] 16
$IV = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("Password")

$cipher = [Org.BouncyCastle.Security.CipherUtilities]::GetCipher("AES/GCM/NOPADDING")
$aesKeyParam = [Org.BouncyCastle.Security.ParameterUtilities]::CreateKeyParameter("AES", $key)
$keyAndIVparam = New-Object Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.ParametersWithIV $aesKeyParam, $IV

$cipher.Init($true,$aesKeyParam)
```

I think it is something wrong with my key's format but I am not sure what's the standard for GCM.

Comment: 1st, make sure your key is only 128, 192, or 256 bits after converting your private key from Base64.  2nd, the last line should be `$cipher.Init($true, $keyAndIVparam)`

Comment: My key is in base64 format with 1624 bytes. But how could I convert it to 256 bits? According to https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/util/PrivateKeyFactory.html , PKCS#8 is required but it doesn't mention the size of key

Comment: You are mixing apples and orange cars here. PKCS8 is used to store the private key of an asymmetric algorithm. AES is a symmetric algorithm. Completely different, the keys for one kind of algorithm make no sense in the other kind. You probably need to step back a little bit and see how you came to this point. Perhaps you're meant to be using hybrid encryption, where a random symmetric key K is generated and used in AES to encrypt data and then K is encrypted with the asymmetric algorithm. More details might help to resolve this.

Comment: I don't mean to use hybrid... I want to use AESGCM only but not sure about the syntax to provide private key to bouncycastle's function